# What is the word for when anachronisms are used in movies set in modern day

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for when anachronisms are used in movies set in modern day? This is deliberately  done to produce a distinct style.
This style is used in the TV show "Pushing Daisies" and the film "The Brothers Bloom".

Comment: No, not anachronisms. This is done deliberately by the director to produce a distinct, quirky style.

Comment: They are still anachronisms. Dressing like someone from the 18th century may be quirky but that's _because_ it's anachronsitic.

Comment: True, but it is not to word I am looking for. The word is for when anachronisms are deliberately used in media to produce the style. Perhaps I should edit my question. I wasn't very clear

Comment: "Anachronism" can be a neutral or positive word, I think. An anachronism can be deliberate if the context indicates it. "One of the trademarks of Samurai Champloo is its imaginative use of anachronism." http://www.spookhouse.net/angelynx/comics/anachronisms.html

Comment: That is a good point Ipf

Comment: I don't think this has been answered, in fact. The term we're looking for (and, granted; it may not exist!) certainly refers to an intentional use of an anachronism. But the thing is its own beast! I think of it as being what an 'easter egg' would be in software...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called ***skeuomorphs***.

From [Wikipedia's article on *skeuomorphs*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph):

> A skeuomorph is a derivative object that **retains ornamental design cues** from structures that were necessary in the original.[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) Examples include pottery embellished with imitation rivets reminiscent of similar pots made of metal.
>
> A similar alternative definition of skeuomorph is "a physical ornament or design on an object made to resemble another material or technique". This definition is broader in scope, as it **can be applied to design elements that still serve the same function as they did in a previous design**.
>
> Skeuomorphs are **deliberately employed to make the new look comfortably old** and familiar.

In movie and film specifically, they are often called **period** objects or artifacts.

Comment: Dan, skeuomorph is almost entirely used to refer to, when, iPhone designers use "brown paper or leather backgrounds" on "notebooks" and the like in apps.  ie, as in the sentence "Jonny Ives got rid of all the skeuomorph shit". The word was more or less invenetd to cover that situation, "iPhone design issues."  I don't, really, see that word being used in connection to, uh, whatever the hell this question is about, in film and TV.